Create Named Credential with authentication and user id in url parameters
I have an endpoint with the following format:
https://test.com/api?salesforce=123&agent=123
Do Named Credentials allow me to store the salesforce value in the Named Credentials associated External Credential? In addition, the agent value is a per user value. I make this call when a Salesforce user access the page. I'm tempted to store this value on the user record and append it to the url before doing the callout, but that doesn't seem to be best practice. Using a Custom Setting is also tempting to solve this, but that doesn't appear ot be best practice either.

This isn't supported by Named Credentials, as it is considered exploitable. Consider if you can use an Authorization header (even Basic Authentication is better than this) or POST form data (where you can at least use $Credential merge fields). If you can't do either, then you can use custom settings or custom metadata, although ideally you want to have them in a protected managed package or use encryption to make it difficult to decrypt for an average user (and typically even admins).
